# CSS Transition Does Not Fire onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, onbeforeunload

I have a nutty client who'd like a large CSS transition on every page unload on her site.

This Fiddle works as intended with the delay, easing, and duration:  http://jsfiddle.net/kLW4C/

However when I try to implement the exact same (I think) code here: http://nolaflash.com/transition.html the transition does not occur.

Page code is as follows.  Why does it work in the Fiddle and not in the page?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
    window.onload=function(){
        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById('myLink').className = 'out';
        }
    }//]]>
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#myLink {
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    background:#CCC;
    transition-property: background color;
    transition-duration: 12.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 6.5s;
}
#myLink.out {
    background:#CC0000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body id="bod" class='in'>

<a href='https://www.google.com' id='myLink'>click me and watch me go red before the page unloads</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `jsfiddle` didn't work for me on `Firefox`. If I put an `alert()` inside your `window.onbeforeunload` it doesn't fire either.

Comment: Oddly this faster version works in FF http://jsfiddle.net/X5vKS/   I guess the onbeforeunload does not wait for the transition.

Comment: That one jsfiddle.net/X5vKS worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**beforeunload** is supposed to be used for a prompt.

According to the spec, if the page **is** to be unloaded the "salvageable" flag is set to FALSE, which is likely the cause preventing your transition.

See: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/history.html#unloading-documents

Comment: (so I guess you can forward that to your client and save your sanity)

Comment: It turns out also that if I use no delay and say 300ms duration that all browsers do render it.  So the delay and duration were prevented by the unload- onbeforeunload did not wait for them to complete.

Comment: And hope the client will understand and accept that that's not possible (:

Comment: I imagine she'll pitch a fit.  But if I use jQuery to add a timeOut to **all links** I can simply use that to buy the time to play the animation overlay she wants.

Comment: Benefit to the user: less than useless.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by blocking all link behavior until the page transition ends, then advancing to the next page. Though I'm with you, I wouldn't necessarily recommend this behavior.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    body {
        transition: 5s; 
   }
    .red {
         background: red;   
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com">test</a>
<script>
var pageTransition=function(){
     // save url for later   
    var nextLink;
    var links=document.querySelectorAll('a');
    var body=document.querySelector('body');

    // I was transitioning the body, you'll need browser-specific listeners
    body.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e){
        // navigate to next page after transition
        window.location=nextLink;
    });
    // disable all links, save url for later
     for(i=0; i<links.length; i++){
         links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
            nextLink=e.target.href;
            body.className+=" red";
            e.preventDefault();
         });
     }
}();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for your problem. Following code works for a single anchor. Similarly you can bind event to all anchors on the same page with jquery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
#myLink {
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    background:#CCC;
    transition-property: background color;
    transition-duration: 4.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
#myLink.out {
    background:#CC0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<script>
function makeDelay(obj){

setTimeout(function(){
     window.location.href = obj.href;
},5000);

document.getElementById('myLink').className = 'out';
    return false;
}
</script>
<body id="bod" class='in'>

<a href='http://www.bing.com' id='myLink' onClick="makeDelay(this);return false;">click me and watch me go red before the page unloads</a>

</body>
</html>
```